# Add account email conditionally on Customer processing Order email notification in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, email-notifications

So this is more of my solution here but I wanted to open this up to see if the community could find a better alternative or potentially find use for this solve.

Our client asked us for the following alteration to the email order receipts received on order creation: *The receipts should go to the account holder and cc the billing email if it's different*

As we know Woocommerce by default sends the order receipt (Customer Processing) based on only the set **billing_email** on checkout so I started to look for a way to add on the tack on the account owner email to it as well.

I did some digging and found a few answers on Stackoverflow on how to do this and the proposed solution utilized the **woocommerce_email_recipient_customer_processing_order** built-in function. This approach would only add on the email in the "to" header -less than ideal. It also doesn't account for potential duplicate sends to the same email address which, at least in the case of our server here, caused the email to not be delivered. No bueno.

The function below represents a work around this wherein we're calling upon the WP Core function **wp_get_current_user()** to obtain the email that the user is associated with and then checking whether it's the same as the billing email.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_headers', 'add_email_recipient', 10, 3);

function add_email_recipient($header, $email_id, $order) {
    // Only for "Customer Processing Emails"  email notifications
    if( ! ( 'customer_processing_order' == $email_id ) ) return;
    $curr_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $account_holder_email = $curr_user->user_email;
    $billing_email = $order->get_billing_email();
    $header ='';
    if ( $account_holder_email != $billing_email ) {
        $header .= 'Cc: '.$account_holder_email;
    }
    return $header;
}
```

The logic intends to flow the following way:

- Adjust the woocommerce email headers
- If the email is the "customer_processing_order" continue
- Get the current user email
- Get the billing email set in the order
- assign a CC field of the current user email
- done

As far as I could tell there wasn't an easier way to handle this so I'm posting this up here in the hopes to see if someone else has a more elegant solution. The above code works by placing in the child theme **functions.php**.

Comment: The customer **"order"** email notifications uses already the billing email address by default in Woocommerce… The user account email is used for **"account"** related email notifications. So you should rethink/reword your question and related code. So for customer Processing order notification, the billing email is used (without need of any code)

Comment: @LoicTheAztec - you're right in that the order email only use billing email address, however the client specifically asked for "account holder email" to be notified upon order submission but only if the email was different from the billing email. Perhaps I'm missing something here - but this was the only way I could approach this...any suggestions on how to do it differently?

Answer (score 3):

> You can't get the current user or the current user ID on email notification hooks. 
>   You need first to get the **customer ID from the order**, then you can get the `WP_User` object to get the account email.

There is 2 different ways to add the customer account email when it's different from the order billing email in Customer processing order email notification:

1) Add the customer account email as an additional recipient:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_customer_processing_order', 'add_customer_processing_order_email_recipient', 10, 2 );
function add_customer_processing_order_email_recipient( $recipient, $order ) {
    // Not in backend (avoiding errors)
    if( is_admin() ) return $recipient;

    if( $order->get_customer_id() > 0 ){

        // Get the customer WP_User object
        $wp_user = new WP_User($order->get_customer_id());

        if ( $wp_user->user_email != $order->get_billing_email() ) {
            // Add account user email  to existing recipient
            $recipient .= ','.$wp_user->user_email;
        }
    }

    return $recipient;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (active theme). It should works.

---

2) Add the customer account email as a CC email address:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_headers', 'add_cc_email_to_headers', 10, 3);
function add_cc_email_to_headers($header, $email_id, $order) {
    // Only for "Customer Processing Emails"  email notifications
    if( 'customer_processing_order' == $email_id ) {

        if( $order->get_customer_id() > 0 ){
            // Get the customer WP_User object
            $wp_user = new WP_User($order->get_customer_id());

            if ( $wp_user->user_email != $order->get_billing_email() ) {
                $header .= 'Cc: ' . utf8_decode($order->get_formatted_billing_full_name() . ' <' . $wp_user->user_email . '>') . "\r\n";
            }
        }
    }
    return $header;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (active theme). It should works.

Comment: I appreciate the response ! I had a question though "$curr_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $account_holder_email = $curr_user->user_email;" It seems to me that this is basically doing the job ow what you're trying to get in terms of customer id. You're using WP_User by get customer id, I'm getting current user because that's what it should be, is the current user that's logged in that's using the function. Perhaps I'm missing something here. I do see your approach as a different way to approach it though

Comment: @KaustavAcharya Sorry but your code don't work, `$curr_user = wp_get_current_user();` can't work as this is not related to front end (so there is no current user available),  As you can see both hooks are related to Order data (from backend)…  I know exactly what I am talking about. The only way to get the user is from the order customer ID. The code from this answer really works and you have 2 different options. There is no other ways. So you should consider that as a good answer.

Comment: Ah I see what you're saying and there's no way you would have known that it was invoked earlier in the stream and was set globally which is why my portion works but it wouldn't on another build. Thank you for your help! I adjusted based on your suggestion and appreciate the feedback here! hopefully this'll help others out!